# How can daemons source environment variables on a machine without persistent storage

Tags: rhel, environment-variables, daemon, yocto, bitbake

I'm working on a Yocto Project build of an AARCH64 system, where I need the `monit` daemon (or at least a process started by monit) to access an environment variable I'm setting.

It's my understanding that normally creating a script under `/etc/profile.d` would work, but since there's no persistent storage on the machine, I'm pretty sure the `monit` daemon is started before that script is created in `profile.d` (I created it under a `do_install()` function in a bitbake recipe).

I do have a workaround where I just export the environment variable in the scripts called by monit, but that feels like the incorrect way to do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say there isn't persistent storage. There has to be at least **some** persistent storage, for instance that has all systemd files etc. Anyway, `/etc/profile.d` et al are only sourced by shells. Check the `Environment` and `EnvironmentFile` directives in the man pages of [`systemd.exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html).

Comment: Best bet would be to modify your persistent image so that the service start up script has a dependency that makes it start after the env files are populated, and then have systemd read those env files.

Comment: "creating a script under /etc/profile.d would work" - no, it wouldn't. At least not for a daemon started by sysV init or systemd. Assuming this is using systemd you need to define the environment in the unit file. https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service

Comment: @symcbean, yep I realized that the monit daemon was started as a systemd unit, so I had to set the environment variable in the monit.service file.